# How do you say ‘curate’ in Esperanto?

Tags: single-word-requests

I am not referring to the noun, which is a religious term, and is covered by both Wells and Benson, but to the verb (i.e., to guarantee the quality of), which is in neither Wells nor Benson, although both have the related noun ‘curator’ [‘kuratoro’], but Butler does not show ‘kuratoro’ to have a verb form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En la tradukaro de Mozilla [mi trovas](https://transvision.mozfr.org/?recherche=curated&repo=gecko_strings&sourcelocale=en-US&locale=eo&search_type=strings) `revizii`, kiu [laŭ PIV](https://vortaro.net/#revizii_kdc) signifas:

> Oficiale elnombri, kontrolante pri taŭgeco, legitimeco ks

La normala verbo estus `konservi` (la difino de `kuratoro` estas `konservisto`).

Depende de la kunteksto oni povus uzi:

1. `konservi`
2. `prizorgi`, teni bonstata.
3. `revizii` ĉar tio kovras grandan parton de la taskoj de kuratoro: zorge kontroli ĉu aferoj taŭgas kaj inventari/elnombri ilin, aldonante aŭ forigante laŭ ilia taŭgeco.
4. se vi sentas vin kuraĝa, vi povus uzi `kurat-i`. Tion pravigetus la ne establita regulo pritrakti `-oro` kiel `-ulo` aŭ `-isto`. En la lingvo oni jam havas jenajn parojn `inspekt-oro->inspekt-i`,`rekvizit-oro->rekvizit-i/-isto`, `administrat-oro->administr-i`.